# Converting JSON date(ticks) to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, json, date-conversion

Does anyone know how to convert a JSON date(ticks) to an NSDate in Objective-C? Can someone post some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing here but your JSON value is the number of milliseconds since 1970, right? You can use NSDate's `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` method to return an NSDate object with the correct time. Just make sure to convert the JSON milliseconds number to seconds before passing it to NSDate-- Cocoa uses NSTimeInterval in most places, which represents an interval in seconds.

Comment: Thanks Marc. That worked for me. Do you know how to display the NSDate to the local time zone of the client?

Comment: Also, do you know how go from NSDate back Date(ticks) to prepare the JSON object to be sent to a .net webservice?

Answer (score 2):

It goes roughly like this:

```
// Input string is something like: "/Date(1292851800000+0100)/" where
// 1292851800000 is milliseconds since 1970 and +0100 is the timezone
NSString *inputString = [item objectForKey:@"DateTimeSession"];

// This will tell number of seconds to add according to your default timezone
// Note: if you don't care about timezone changes, just delete/comment it out
NSInteger offset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];

// A range of NSMakeRange(6, 10) will generate "1292851800" from "/Date(1292851800000+0100)/"
// as in example above. We crop additional three zeros, because "dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:"
// wants seconds, not milliseconds; since 1 second is equal to 1000 milliseconds, this will work.
// Note: if you don't care about timezone changes, just chop out "dateByAddingTimeInterval:offset" part
NSDate *date = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
                 [[inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 10)] intValue]]
                dateByAddingTimeInterval:offset];
```

(from https://gist.github.com/726910)

Comment: This solution is fragile. It works only if the number has exactly 13 digits (or 10, if you drop the microseconds). It will not work for all dates before September 2001.

Comment: Martin, you're correct. I hope referenced gist link will provide you more context.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to detect the client's locale in order to be able to do that, and unless your client knows how to do that, there's probably not much point.

NSDate's descriptionWithLocale: would be the way you format it for another locale. And timeIntervalSince1970 will go back to the (seconds) since 1970, which you could multiply by 1000 to get ms to return to the client. It's all in the NSDate documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

According to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx ticks begin on Jan 1, 0001 so `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:` is not automatically setup to work with ticks.  You can still use this method but should adjust for the difference.